# layout neo4j graph based on points

Tags: neo4j

I have a neo4j database with some data stored in Points (e.g. `coordinates: point({srid:4326, x:-4.224099535439225, y:52.10621881941465})`).

I want the neo4j browser to honour these points when laying out the graph visually. Is there a way to interact with its layout manager, and ask it to use these points?

Comment: I hope those aren't longitude and latitude measurements? [10*-13 is to within ~ 1Å](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude) - so you're down to ~100th of the width of a Hydrogen atom! You must have some very good instruments! :-) p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Thanks! They are, actually - but converted from northing/easting so it's just the default level of accuracy as spat out by my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it, without using third-party visualisation software

Comment: Don't forget to mark your own answer as correct (when you can) as it might help other users in the future!

Comment: Maybe you could provide a link to where you found the answer - and the text that shows that this is the case? Link only answers are generally  discouraged here (link rot, plus the StackExchange ethos of trying to be a one-stop-shop for Q&A.